# Stuck on a really simple chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

So I'm going through a PDE book, and working on deriving the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation. The derivation obviously doesn't show all of the calculations/steps involved that are easy, but while doing one, I think I'm having a brain fog moment, and I keep making some mistake? Can someone help me figure out why I'm wrong?

What I have is Laplace's equation in 2-D, $$u_{x_1x_1}+u_{x_2x_2} = 0$$

Now, we let $u(x) = v(r)$ where $r=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}$ and work out the partial derivatives $u_{x_1}$ and then $u_{x_1x_1}$ by the chain rule.

I get $u_{x_1} = v'(r)\frac{x}{r}$ and then use the chain rule again to get $u_{x_1x_1}$ but, where the book says it should be $$u_{x_1x_1} = v''(r)\frac{x^2}{r^2} + v'(r)\bigg(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x^2}{r^3}\bigg)$$
I get
$$u_{x_1x_1} = v''(r)\frac{x^2}{r^2} + v'(r)\bigg(\frac{x}{r^2} - \frac{x^3}{r^4}\bigg)$$

This is because, if I'm thinking of this correctly, won't we find $u_{x_1x_1}$ by $(u_{x_1})_rr_{x_1}$? Which would be
$$u_{x_1x_1} = \bigg[v'(r)\bigg(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x^2}{r^3}\bigg) + \frac{x}{r}v'(r)\bigg]. \frac{x}{r}$$

I clearly know there's an error in the way I'm doing this, but I can't really figure out what. Can someone help?

Comment: As you write $u_{x_1} = v'(r) \frac{x_1}{r}$. One more derivative, we get $u_{x_1 x_1} = (v'(r) \frac{x_1}{r})_{x_1} = (v'(r))_{x_1} + v'(r)(\frac{x_1}{r})_{x_1} = v''(r) \frac{x^2_1}{r^2} + v'(r) \frac{r - x_1 r_{x_1}}{r^2} = v''(r) \frac{x^2_1}{r^2} + v'(r) \frac{r - x_1 \frac{x_1}{r}}{r^2}$

Comment: Wait, so if I'm understanding this right, we only apply the chain rule to the $v'(r)(\frac{x_1}{r})_{x_1}$ term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do the usual direct chain rule:
$$
u_{x_1}=v'(r)\frac{x_1}{r}
$$
$$
u_{x_1x_1}=v''(r)\frac{x_1}{r
}\frac{x_1}{r}+v'(r)\frac{r-x_1{\frac{x_1}{r}}}{r^2}
$$
Simplifies to
$$
u_{x_1x_1} = v''(r)\frac{x_1^2}{r^2} + v'(r)\bigg(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x_1^2}{r^3}\bigg)
$$

---

> won't we find $u_{x_1x_1}$ by $(u_{x_1})_rr_{x_1}$?

Note that $u_{x_1}$ is a function of $r,v'(r),x_1$
and $r$ is a function of $x_1, x_2$, so the chain rule gives

$$
\frac{\partial u_{x_1}}{\partial x_1}=
\frac{\partial u_{x_1}}{\partial r}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_1}+
\frac{\partial u_{x_1}}{\partial v'(r)}
\frac{\partial v'(r)}{\partial x_1}
+
\frac{\partial u_{x_1}}{\partial x_1}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}$$
The first term reduces to
$$
-v'(r)\frac{x_1}{r^2}\frac{x_1}{r}
$$
The second term reduces to
$$
\frac{x_1}{r
}v''(r)\frac{x_1}{r}
$$
The last term reduces to
$$
v'(r)\frac{1}{r}
$$
Which, again, returns to the answer provided by the book

Comment: The second part made it a lot more clear, thank you!

Comment: Using the subscript notation: $$\begin{align}u_{x_1x_1}&=[v_r~r^{-1}~x_1]_{x_1}&&\text{evaluation of }u_{x_1}\\[1ex]&=[v_r]_{x_1}~r^{-1}~x_1+v_r~[r^{-1}]_{x_1}~x_1+v_r~r^{-1}~[x_1]_{x_1}&&\textbf{product rule}\\[1ex]&=(v_{rr}~r_{x_1})~r^{-1}~x_1+v_r~(-r^{-2}~r_{x_1})~x_1+v_r~r^{-1}&&\text{chain rule}\\[1ex]&=v_{rr}~r^{-2}~x_1^2-v_r~r^{-3}~x_1^2+v_r~r^{-1}&&\text{evaluation of }r_{x_1}=r^{-1}~x_1\end{align}$$